# C++ regex exclusion double quotes not working

Tags: c++, regex

I am considering input files with lines like

```
"20170103","MW JANE DOE","NL01 INGB 1234 5678 90","NL02 INGB 1234 5678 90","GT","Af","12,34","Internetbankieren","Mededeling_3"
"20170102","MW JANE DOE","NL01 INGB 1234 5678 90","NL02 INGB 1234 5678 90","GT","Af","12,34","Internetbankieren","Mededeling_2"
"20170101","MW JANE DOE","NL01 INGB 1234 5678 90","NL02 INGB 1234 5678 90","GT","Af","12,34","Internetbankieren","Mededeling_1"
```

. I want to get the separate strings WITHOUT THE DOUBLE QUOTES and store them in `std::vector<std::string>`. So, for instance, I want to have `20170101`, `MW JANE DOE`, `NL01 INGB 1234 5678 90`, `NL02 INGB 1234 5678 90`, `GT`, `Af`, `12,34`, `Internetbankieren`, and `Mededeling_1` as a result.

I try to do so with the code

```
std::regex re("\"(.*?)\"");
std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> it (line.begin(),line.end(),re);
std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> end;
std::vector<std::string> lineParts;
std::string linePart="";

// Split 'line' into line parts and save these in the vector 'lineParts'.
while (it!=end)
{
    linePart=it->str();
    std::cout<<linePart<<std::endl; // Print substring.
    lineParts.push_back(linePart);
    ++it;
}
```

However, the double quotes are still included in the elements of `lineParts`, even though I used the regex `"\"(.*?)\""` so that supposedly only the part within the double quotes is saved, and not the double quotes themselves.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `linePart=it->str(1);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution seems to work, though I don't understand what this `(1)` does. Do you perhaps know where this usage is documented?

Comment: @Adriaan: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pattern with a *capturing group*. So, when your regex finds a match, the double quotes are part of the *whole* match value (that is stored in the `[0]`th element), but the captured part is stored in the `[1]`th element.

So, you just need to access capturing group #1 contents:

```
linePart=it->str(1);
```

See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html#grammar) *Finding a Regex Match*:

> When the function call returns true, you can call the `str()`, `position()`, and `length()` member functions of the match_results object to get the text that was matched, or the starting position and its length of the match relative to the subject string. Call these member functions without a parameter or with 0 as the parameter to get the overall regex match. **Call them passing 1 or greater to get the match of a particular capturing group.** The `size()` member function indicates the number of capturing groups plus one for the overall match. Thus you can pass a value up to `size()-1` to the other three member functions.

Comment: If anyone needs to get "quoted" substrings using a regex use `std::regex re("\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\s\\S][^\"\\\\]*)*)\"");`. Or, better, ``std::regex re("(?:^|[^\\\\])(?:\\\\{2})*\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\s\\S][^\"\\\\]*)*)\"");`` - and grab Group 1 value.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, [`regex_iterator::operator->`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator/operator*) returns a [`match_results`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) and [`match_results::str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/str) is defaulted to 0:

> The first `sub_match` (index `0`) contained in a `match_result` always represents the full match within a target sequence made by a `regex`, and subsequent `sub_matches` represent sub-expression matches corresponding in sequence to the left parenthesis delimiting the sub-expression in the `regex`

So the problem with your code is you're not using `linePart = it->str(1)`.

A better solution would be to use a `regex_token_iterator`. With whitch you could just use your `re` to directly initialize `lineParts`:

```
vector<string> lineParts { sregex_token_iterator(cbegin(line), cend(line), re, 1), sregex_tokent_iterator() };
```

---

But I'd just like to point out that [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) introduced [`quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) does exactly what you're trying to do here, and more (it even handles escaped quotes for you!) It'd just be a shame not to use it.

You probably are already getting your input from a stream, but just in the case you're not you'd need to initialize an `istringstream`, for the purposes of example I'll call mine: `line`. Then you can use `quoted` to populate `lineParts` like this:

```
for(string linePart; line >> quoted(linePart); line.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ',')) {
    lineParts.push_back(linePart);
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/iES7Vi)